# Write atomically to multiple zookeeper nodes using Apache Curator Framework?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

Is it possible to write data to multiple zookeeper nodes? Possibly by using any of the [Apache Curator framework](http://curator.apache.org/) recipes? Couldn't really see any API, but I thought it wouldn't be a bad idea to ask it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ZooKeeper has "transaction" methods that can do multiple atomic writes (1). Curator exposes these methods through its DSL (2). Note: The Curator DSL improved in version 3.0.x (3).

1. https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.9/api/org/apache/zookeeper/ZooKeeper.html#multi(java.lang.Iterable)
2. https://github.com/apache/curator/blob/master/curator-examples/src/main/java/framework/TransactionExamples.java
3. https://github.com/apache/curator/blob/CURATOR-3.0/curator-examples/src/main/java/framework/TransactionExamples.java